# How long am I going to be rate-limited for "too many requests"?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, ban

#### From [Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376060/201200)

My IP address was banned on March 13. But I wasn't using Tor (and I'm not a Tor node.)...

[image: Too many requests error page]

Of course, my first reaction was to sent mail as instructed, but as this happened on Saturday, I've received back quickly a message explaining that there are no support on week-end....

For my understanding: I was working on SO the day before (March 12, but I don't remember the clock time precisely) when SO was coming down. I was writing a post... After some manual retries, I've initiated a little [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) loop running `wget` on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) until the standard SO's title could be read, something like every 120 seconds... So I would imagine that this did not look like a regular human interacting with the site and thus the ban was legitimate.

But how long is this going to last?

I've finally used `ssh -D somewhereelse` as a *proxy SOCKS* in order to be able to terminate [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71492678/1765658). But I was surprised about the duration of the ban. After I stopped my *wget loop*, test from browser after one hour, then one day was unsuccessful.

After more than one day, I've finally sent my question by e-mail, to *`team At SE.com`*, but that was on Sunday... Do some test on Monday, and finally I've stopped my SOCKS proxy Tuesday, maybe something like 72 hours after I was banned.

Is this correct, or did the ban system use a progressive ban time regarding number of tries I submitted?

Comment: I have a proper uptime monitor polling 2 SE chat servers, mse, Su and so every minute with no issues. I don't think doing so every 120s would cause a too many requests rate limit

Comment: ...Have you tried following the advice in the note there that says "*if you believe this to be in error, please contact us at team@stackexchange.com*"? I had this happen to me a bit ago (caused by a request-heavy userscript), and they got back to me within a few hours with detail about the block. I imagine that this issue isn't really something that anyone but staff can help with.

Comment: These general rate-limit IP blocs *typically* last 10 to 15 minutes. If your use is/was legitimate and the general IP block rate-limit lasts *substantially* longer than that, then you are best off using the ["Contact"/"contact us" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to contact Stack Exchange. There have been times in the past where they have misconfigured the rate limiting such that it *never* expires for an IP once triggered. You're *way* past the normal timeframe for this, so *contact them*.

Comment: A *single* request every 120 seconds shouldn't be sufficient to trigger the general IP rate-limiting block. It usually takes *substantially* more traffic than that to trigger these blocks.

Comment: @zcoop98 Of course, unfurtunely, This happen at saturday, I've become quickly a message explaining: no support on week-end...

Comment: Are you on some kind of public network? (School / work?)

Comment: What is the total number of requests? Opening 50 pages with a 3 seconds delay has never been a problem (daily). The same with 2,000 pages ([Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)'ting) with a 16 seconds delay (9-12 months interval).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Interesting! It's maybe consecutive to SSL fails and some bug in my script... I realize when connection fail **because of** security fail, the 120 second delay won't be executed... I have to review my shell and try to build a fake server to make some tests...

Comment: @F.Hauri This is why every BASH script I ever started eventually got redone in Python as the complexity grows. It's not a full fledged programming language and always seems to have weird errors. Bash is just more convenient for running system commands, but you can do that in Python with a little finagling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Mea culpa

From *[Log in to a site (Stack Overflow) by Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223204/1765658)*, I've created a [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) script with some fun features: [getSo.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/getSo.sh.txt).

I just corrected a bug now: my endless loop (`while true`) made a 120 seconds delay, but only when a correct read was done.

The bug was: when connection fail, script loop immediately in order to try again. As SO was restarting, requests were unsuccessful and the script did a lot of retries.

The more: once banned for the first grace period, as I was sleeping, the script did continue to make non temporised tries...

I understand now the reason I was banned for a long time.

Comment: Its a bit more work, but have you considered setting up a 'proper' monitoring thing? :D  I've been running https://sourcegraph.github.io/checkup/ for some semi internal services. In theory I've upgraded to uptime kuma https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma which is nice but checkup is easier/better for linking to other people since its dashboard has graphs . Needs a web server and stuff but Its a much better setup

Comment: Maybe just don't create such scripts to begin with? Stack Overflow **isn't a game**. Using script is always a risk, unless you really need it for some reason, better not take such risk. Imagine SO didn't have such good protection. Your script would have been **actual DDoS attack on SO**. Funny, right? Well, no.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar No, just a plain DoS attack. Not distributed. And it should have generated so little traffic that SO would barely even notice it. It could be a very different matter if many other people also used that script, but in that case it would have a more rigorous development process, and someone would quickly point out the bug, right?