# Why does Stack Overflow not work? It says the site is offline

Tags: bug

[image: error image]

Why do I have this error?

Comment: Because the site is down. See https://www.stackstatus.net/

Comment: @Justin After the past incidences, I think it is safe to assume that the cause of the downtime is not maintenance...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, it will always say that. But building a whole series of pages dedicated to showing what the problem is this time when they probably won't know in the first 15 minutes anyway, seems like a waste of time.

Comment: Unless you're a paying SO for Teams customer, it is not expected to be on 24/7. It mostly is but that isn't a contractual obligation.

Comment: Slightly related: *[Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes)* (February 2022 through May 2022)

Comment: August 2022: every day around the same time you go offline. Is that really for maintenance or what is it? It is INCREDIBLY annoying (I am in CEST)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the time you posted your question, sites across the network aside from Meta Stack Exchange (this site) and [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) were experiencing frequent outage with very intermittent spurts of normal operation. The downtime lasted for a couple of hours. Meta SE and Meta SO staying up appears to be due to them being hosted on separate servers from the rest of the network.

Per [this Stack Status incident](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/8d533a56-bacb-48e3-baa5-8266d93f08c3), the problem appeared to be due to an "unusually high load on our servers", thus making this very much *not* a planned downtime, as the error page you saw mentions. Stack Exchange site reliability engineers made "some adjustments to our back end systems to try and mitigate the ongoing issues", which seems to have, at the present time, resolved the problem.

The incident's status is still set to "degraded" which means Stack Exchange is not quite satisfied enough to mark the incident as resolved. Once that changes, we can be somewhat confident that this outage, specifically, has been fully mitigated.

Comment: Well doubt they can ever mark DDoS attack outage as "resolved" as there's no way to 100% *prevent* such attacks, only try to mitigate it after it already started and made damage. (i.e. block the IP ranges used by attacker)