# The StackStatus website does not resolve without a preceding "www" in the URL

Tags: bug, 408-timeout, stackstatus

The somewhat-recently launched [StackStatus website](https://www.stackstatus.net/) requires `www` in order to properly resolve. Without it, the connection to the website will eventually time out.

For clarity:

- Working: https://www.stackstatus.net/
- Not working: https://stackstatus.net/

This is inconsistent with current network-wide practices, for example on Stack Overflow, where https://stackoverflow.com/ resolves correctly.

I recognized this when I attempted to navigate to the site via the link provided in [this recently-featured announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381161/622284). I've adjusted the link there to use the currently-working URL for the time being.

Could the URL without `www` preceding it be adjusted to resolve to the Stack Status site?

Comment: Based on comments from the original announcement, it sounds like this won't be fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378941/improvements-to-site-status-and-incident-communication#comment1266142_378941

Comment: Ah, shame. Didn't see that discussion. Understandable, though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While we won't be able to immediately address the behavior of the URL without `www.` (ref: [Josh's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378941/improvements-to-site-status-and-incident-communication#comment1266142_378941)), I have created a work item internally to ensure that all of our outward-facing links to the status page are presented with `https://` and `www.`. Currently this is inconsistent in our codebase, primarily because many of the "offline" pages are - by definition and necessity - static HTML files that don't pull from some common environment variable or database.

*That* work is now complete as of 2022-11-28, described here:

- [Change the HTTP status blog links to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384161/165455)

That said, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for the reported symptom in *this* report will be separate, and currently has no defined timeline.

Answer (score 5):

FYI: https://www.isstackoverflowdownforeveryoneorjustme.com works with and without HTTPS, with and without "www."

Comment: uh... that's a long link. A shorter one would be better... something like: issedown.com

Comment: Never heard/seen that.... when was this domain created?