# The 'You cannot post due to spam and abuse' message should appear when I click 'Ask question' instead of 'Post your question'

Tags: feature-request, ip-ban, tor

I use Tor for anonymity and I often see the *Your post could not be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network* message, because apparently some malicious user got the same exit node when they used it to post abuse.

When this happens I reset identity and try again. But it could save time if the system just informed us sooner that our network is blocked. This could also affect people who are not using Tor and are just unlucky and share a network with spammers, and could might not know how to just *try again*, so their post is lost.

My feature request is, any conditions that would cause a post to be blocked should be checked at the time of clicking 'Ask Question' also and denied already, to spare people their time if they are attempting to post from a blacklisted network.

I know these IP blocks are necessary to block known bad sources, but there is no reason not to block users before they spend any time trying to write a post, and not after.

Comment: Technically, if you *were* spamming or abusive, it seems nice to waste their time as much as possible. I feel like this is one of those cases where the bad eggs ruin it for everyone.

Comment: Related: *[Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes?rq=1)*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What is the point? Their spam is blocked either way. And besides arent most spammers actually scripts anyway?

Comment: There's quite a lot of humans who do it too. Not all is scripted.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Do they really expect to see their spam cause enough sales to increase their profits by anywhere near even minimum wage?